# Can I make if statement just for one use in loop?

Tags: python, if-statement, pyautogui

Here's the code:

```
while 1:

    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('first323232.png', confidence=0.8) != None:

        click(1021,881)

        kibord()

        time.sleep(2)

        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('grzonskie.png', confidence=0.8) != None:

            rest()

            if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('hp.png', confidence = 0.8) != None:

                click(1132,50)

                kibord()

                time.sleep(1)

        else:

            continue
```

I want to make `if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('grzonskie.png', confidence = 0.8) != None: rest()` to be used just 1 time. How can i do this? I tried to make it work with break pass and continue statements but it didn't work or i don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: What about using a boolean flag such as `should_check`?

Answer (score 2):

You can add some flag named 'reset' for example and init it to True,
Then check your condition with 'and reset' in the end, if the condition is True you can set the 'reset' flag to False and the condition will never be True again (because anything **and** False is always False).

Good luck!